# Unable to install PyPortfolioOpt

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, cvxpy

When trying to install PyPortfolioOpt using pip it errors out with the following message,

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

However, i do have cvxpy 1.1.3 installed for my Python 3.8. During PyPortfolioOpt installation i see that it is trying to build cvspy wheel with the following condition:

```
Collecting cvxpy<1.1,>=1.0
  Using cached cvxpy-1.0.31.tar.gz (947 kB)
```

I don't see a "Requirement already satisfied" message in the case of cvxpy. It always fails in this process and errors out from the installation. Let me know if there is a fix for this.

Comment: It was easily installed for me using the same `pip install PyPortfolioOpt`. However, the requirements already satified was thrown first and then the cxpy was collected. Upgrade your `setup-tools` `pip` first and then let me know.

Comment: My setuptools is up to date. Using v49.6.0. Is the cvxpy condition a potential problem? I've also tried installation through poetry and that too has failed for me with an "[Assertion Error]". Any way to resolve this?

Comment: I [author of PyPortfolioOpt] am currently trying to explore allowing cvxpy >=1.1. The problem is that I have a function which requires integer programming, which was changed in 1.1. Have posted a thread in the cvxpy mailing list, will keep you posted.

Comment: The issues is now resolved on allowing cvxpy>=1.1. Thank you for the update